# presentPopoverFromRect causes an empty view, but using segue it works fine

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios5, xcode4, uipopovercontroller

I am making an iPad app where I programmatically place UIButtons on a UIImageView inside a UIScrollView.

When someone pushes one of these buttons I would like to present a UIPopover. Since the buttons have been added programmatically, I also have to present the popover programmatically.

Here is my code for presenting the popover:

```
- (void)buttonHandler:(UIButton *)sender
{
    PushButtonViewController *controller = [[PushButtonViewController alloc] initWithButtonID:@"hej"];
    _pushButtonPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller];

    _pushButtonPopover.delegate = self;

    if(![_pushButtonPopover isPopoverVisible]) {
       [_pushButtonPopover presentPopoverFromRect:sender.bounds inView:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    } else {
        [_pushButtonPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

This is the initializer of the popover view controller:

```
- (id)initWithButtonID:(NSString *)buttonID
{
    self = [super init];
    self.buttonID = buttonID;
    return self;
}
```

The problem is that when I do so, **I get an empty popover:**

[Screenshot 1 - not working](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q0k1idd5c0roymn/screenshot1.png)

However, when I use a pre-inserted button, hooked up with a segue i the Storyboard, **everything works just fine:**

[Screenshot 2 - working fine](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mbuxs6dm2hcewfr/screenshot2.png)

I really hope that you might have some suggestions to what I might be doing wrong. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to have found the answer myself. For some reason you have to instantiate your ViewController from the storyboard like this:

```
PushButtonViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Push Button Popover"];
```

This way the view is displayed correctly.